# How do I get the play button to play a certain song from parse?

Tags: ios, swift

I currently have a title for the currently playing song, and have that same song in parse database, but when I click the play button on my app it plays a random song in the database, rather than the title of the song. How I get the play button to play a certain song in the database?

```
func play(sender: UIButton!){
    //assign each button to play the certain song pertaining to the UILabel
   playing song

    println(self.NameArray)
    println("Song:  + \(Title)")
    println("Artist:  + \(Artist)")
    println("Album:  + \(Album)")


            for dbTitle in self.NameArray{

        if(dbTitle == Title){
            var SongQuery = PFQuery(className: "Songs")
            SongQuery.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(iDArray[SelectedSongNumber], block:{
                (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                if let AudioFileURLTemp = object?.objectForKey("SongFile")?.url{
                    AudioPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: AudioFileURLTemp!))
                    AudioPlayer.play()//currently plays random song
                    println("playing song")
                }
            })

            println("Song in db")

        }else{
            println("Song not in db")
        }

    }


}



 var ObjectIDQuery = PFQuery(className: "Songs")
    ObjectIDQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (objectsArray: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        var objectIDs = objectsArray as! [PFObject]

            for i in 0...objectIDs.count-1{
            self.iDArray.append(objectIDs[i].valueForKey("objectId") as! String)
            self.NameArray.append(objectIDs[i].valueForKey("SongName") as! String)

                }

    })
```

Comment: Do you have an objectID for that specific song? Because you could retrieve the objectID specifically for that one song, and since there is only one object with that objectID, you could retrieve the song

Comment: Each song in the database has its own objectID

Comment: Where do the nameArray and iDArray values come from?  If you retrieving them from Parse, why not just store an array of PFObjects directly? Otherwise, why not query Parse for the Title?

Comment: Just create a PFQuery for "Songs" and set the whereKey for songName=Title then execute your findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock

Comment: is the whereKey the objectForKey?